# Ember Power Select - Label / Value

Tags: ember.js, web-component, ember-power-select

I can't seem to understand how to do the following looking over the [docs](http://www.ember-power-select.com/docs) for "ember power select".

I have a model user:

```
export default Model.extend({
    "state": attr('string')
});
```

Stored as a value in the DB is:  **NY** for state

I also have the following data to load into the ember power select options:

```
stateList: [
    {
        label: 'New Jersey',
        value: 'NJ'
    },
    {
        label: 'New York',
        value: 'NY'
    },
]
```

The following handlebar code will load in the states and display them.  You can search and select the state:

```
{{#power-select 
    options=stateList
    searchField="label"
    selected=state
    onchange=(action (mut state))
    as |state|
}}
    {{state.label}}
{{/power-select}}
```

The issue... on select of **'New York'**, I would like the stored value of **'state'** to be **'NY'**

Right now it's simply storing the entire object.  I understand through **'onchange'** I can set the value, but I don't really understand how you set the value to **'NY'** and have it selected?

I've tried doing

```
this.set('state',selection.value)
```

But I think it's looking for the index of the object, I however simply want to pass 'NY' and not a whole object... is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question is NO(AFAIK). But you can achieve this using computed property.

> Component js code

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  stateList: [{'label': 'New Jersey','value': 'NJ'},{ 'label': 'New York','value': 'NY'}],
  state:'NY',
  selectedState: Ember.computed('state', function(){    
    return this.get('stateList').findBy('value',this.get('state'));
  }),

  actions:{
    setSelectedState(selectedVal){      
      this.set('state',selectedVal.value);
    }
  }
});
```

> Component hbs code

```
{{#power-select 
    options=stateList
    searchField="label"
    selected=selectedState
    onchange=(action 'setSelectedState')
    as |state|
}}
    {{state.label}}
{{/power-select}}
{{yield}}
```

Here is **[Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8894d46f8bca43dfdf42025a1c847aa4?openFiles=templates.components.selected-test.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.selected-test.hbs)**

Comment: The Twiddle does only allow to select an entry once, changing the value doesn't seem possible. Do you have an idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: Here is the updated [twiddle link](https://ember-twiddle.com/8894d46f8bca43dfdf42025a1c847aa4?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.selected-test.hbs). we need to include `<div id="ember-basic-dropdown-wormhole">
</div>` dummy div in application.hbs for ember wormhole addon to place dropdown correclty.